# Is there a database independent way to filter by "None"/"NaN"?

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The following code is database specific:

```
import sqlalchemy
# ...
ergebnis = session.query(
    my_object.attr1).filter(sa.and_(
        my_object.attr2 != 'NaN')).all() # PostgreSQL
        """
        my_object.attr2 != None)).all() # sQLite
        """
```

With PostgreSQL it is "'NaN'", with SQLite "None" (without single quotes). Is there an SQLAlchemy way to do this backend independent?

Comment: `'NaN'` is just a plain string literal in PostgreSQL and has no "special" meaning (at least not in plain SQL - don't know if SQLAlchemy does some magic to that). What datatype is `attr2`?. My guess is you want to check for `NULL` (but without quotes)

Comment: attr2 is float. The problem seems to be that SQLAlchemy provides a "NaN"-string if PostgreSQL returns NULL, and None if SQLite returns NULL. The way, how PostgreSQL or SQLite returns the NULL (as string or NoneType) should be handled by SQLAlchemy and not passed through to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare against the `'NaN'` ("not a number") **float** value, then do an explicit cast to float: `float('NaN')`. In this case SQLAlchemy *should* do the same conversion.

Comment: Python/SQLAlchemy `model.column != float("NaN")` will turn into Postgresql `column != nan` and not work. The error is `column "nan" does not exist`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for Postgres, but I don't know how database-independent it is:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sqla

...

myobject.attr2 != sqla.cast(float("NaN"), sqla.Float)
```